# Drag and Drop .Net Maui

Tags: maui, .net-maui

Is there a way to create a layout with draggable items in the new .net Maui for mobile apps (Android, Ios and WinApp?

I've been searching what is possible to do in the platform and I haven't found something at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is , use CanDrag and AllowDrop.

Find it here [DragdropMaui example](https://github.com/borisoprit/DragdropMaui)

In MainPage.xaml

```
    <Frame Margin="20">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropGestureRecognizer_Drop_1" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </Frame>

            <Label Text="Drag Me away" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="36">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <DragGestureRecognizer CanDrag="True" DragStarting="DragGestureRecognizer_DragStarting_1" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
```

In MainPage.cs

```
 private void DragGestureRecognizer_DragStarting_1(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
{
    var label = (sender as Element)?.Parent as Label;
    e.Data.Properties.Add("Text", label.Text);
}

private void DropGestureRecognizer_Drop_1(object sender, DropEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Data.Properties["Text"].ToString();
    var frame = (sender as Element)?.Parent as Frame;
    frame.Content = new Label
    {
        Text = data
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this only be used to drag elements from within your app into other areas? I'm developing a MAUI Windows app and dragging a file from the desktop into an element in my app which has the AllowDrop property set to true causes an unhandled exception with a message "Value cannot be null".

Comment: @nerdalert  Not sure , maybe start a new question about your dragging from the desktop.